# IONIC [native-file, image-picker] does not work writeFile on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

There is such a method:

```
 public loadGallery():void{
    let options ={
      maximumImagesCount: 20,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      quality: 75
    };
    this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((result) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        this.imgList.push({'win':{id: result[i], title: result[i]}});
      }
      let builder = new xml2js.Builder();
      let xml = builder.buildObject(this.imgList);
      this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory,'mywins.xml', xml, {replace: true});
    },
    function(errmsg){
      console.log('---->'+ errmsg)
    });
  }
```

On Android it works, on iOS it saves only at the first start, at the following only adds to the array when you shoot out the photo, but the file does not overwrite.